# N-gram ignoring line-breaks

Tags: nlp, nltk, n-gram

I am relatively new with nltk but recently I have had a problem and I can't seem to find a solution for it.

I have a text like this

`Monkeys like bananas.`

`The sky is blue.`

I am trying to do bigrams and by using word_tokenizer it creates these bigrams:

`Monkeys like 1
like bananas 1
bananas The 1
The sky 1
sky is 1
is blue 1`

How can I make it work so it doesn't create the bigram

`bananas The 1`
?

```
import nltk 
from nltk.util import ngrams
corpus = open("my.txt").read()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(corpus)
bigrams = ngrams(tokens,2)
print Counter(bigrams)
```

Answer (score 1):

## TLDR;

use `sent_tokenize` before using bigrams. (Make sure punkt is installed by using nltk.download('punkt');

Then:

```
>>> x = nltk.sent_tokenize("The Monkeys like bananas. The sky is blue")
['The Monkeys like bananas.', 'The sky is blue.']

>>> for x in a:
...     list(nltk.bigrams(nltk.word_tokenize(x)))
...
[('The', 'Monkeys'), ('Monkeys', 'like'), ('like', 'bananas'), ('bananas', '.')]
[('The', 'sky'), ('sky', 'is'), ('is', 'blue')]
```

## Details

1) You're missing the point of bigrams.

They are used to train the engine to identify words that are collocated.

So you have to parse the content a little bit before you use bigrams.  Thus the use of `sent_tokenize` followed by `word_tokenize` before using bigrams in the example above. You probably want to remove punctuation as well by preprocessing the text through a proper tokenizer.